# Windows11, New monitor in single monitor setting, displays as 2nd in settings as in a dual-screen setup

Tags: windows, display

Most questions I've found searching deal with their pc not finding the second monitor in a dual-screen setup. I have a gpu and can run dual monitors but I am choosing not to, however, my computer detects two monitors anyway and sometimes I get my windows popping up on another screen that isn't there.

I know it has a built-in display adapter on the motherboard and it works even when I disable it in the device manager. In fact, that's what I usually have to do to use my gpu in game. But since I got my new monitor it seems to not want to recognize it as a single setup, but an extension of my old one. It even has designated it screen 2, even though switching it back to my old monitor still keeps it as screen two and as my main monitor.

It has never been a simple install because of my oem acer mobo and I can never see the bios screen from my gpu but at least it worked well enough without factoring in the new monitor and now I really am going crazy. To put this clearly, short of reinstalling windows to make it forget my old monitor and only ever using this new one, I don't know what else to do to make it work as one, or at least as before.

Every time I restart it I get to my desktop and it's empty or a black screen if it's empty I have to hover over my taskbar and click move and then press an arrow key. I never had to do that when it was one monitor and gpu plus onboard competing, now I have two monitors competing for one spot. I have to do a procedure to make it work that I can't recreate. I just do random things until it works... sometimes it gets worse and only works on my old monitor; so then... I have to switch cables to my old monitor and bring it back into the room and start toggling random settings and switching it back until it feels like working again and I don't know how to make it 'just work' but when I do, I will hopefully breathe a sigh of relief... because I'm out of ideas. Maybe someone can help me because I can't think of anything I might be doing wrong. If there's any help you can offer. I would appreciate it so much.

P.S. I don't plan to use my old monitor ever again, and though I think it's cumbersome to have to take drastic measures, I am willing to erase it from my computer in registry or anything if I have to in order for it to work as desired and as before with my new monitor. It seems there is no easy way to change monitor two to make it monitor one...? And I am waiting and ready to answer any troubleshooting questions or specifics. Thanks again in advance.

(It was on for days working fine but I ran an update today and forgot this would probably happen because it's the third time.)

As of writing this, I have lost all signal to the correct monitor.

So since today, If I disable the onboard drivers I can only view gpu output from my old monitor (perfectly), black screen on new one. Single or double connection, same thing, black screen.
but:

If I re-enable onboard drivers (is the only way now that) I can view my new monitor in the new display from the onboard and the gpu but then I can't even launch most games with that setup and it doesn't seem right to use it.
I need a civilized way to fix this without connecting my old monitor and my new monitor at once I am doing that right now and it's not even working.

It's really confusing because any of the two monitors to my gpu it calls monitor 2 so if I put 'show only on 2' it shows only on my old monitor lol.

Update (solved); So for updating my pc, I had turned on my graphics driver for the onboard/mobo gpu and tethered the hdmi to that on my pc for the update process to go smoothly and be visible. But then I started having issues again. How I was able to solve the problem I think completely was to switch the monitor number to one. But it wasn't simple. Had to connect both monitors at once. Hooked up the main one (new one) to the nvidia gpu unit and the old monitor the my mobo’s built-in display output. Then shut down and started it up again (or you can probably say restarted the computer). At this point I was able to enable my graphics driver in device manager for the built it gpu and get both screens to show in display under settings (they are identical sizes and they showed correctly as such). So, I hit identify to make sure. By this time my main display tethered on the gpu was showing 1. Succes! Didn’t have to change settings in gpu in bios or past  displays info in registry. Shout out to the person who helped me by suggesting the restart and a few other options and then edited out their comment! Restart and connecting both monitors with the onboard's driver's worked to  change the new monitor and designate it correctly. (Whether my motherboard's graphics onboard unit comes from the cpu or a gpu unit directly on the motherboard I'm not sure about but I keep the bios on Auto for video settings.) Thanks for reading and I hope my update helps.

2nd update, much better explanation and settings: While I was able to change my new monitor to monitor one in my pc, when I turn off the drivers for the onboard graphics in device manager it creates two monitors. I want apps to launch in the same screen I was using as monitor one so I choose "display only on monitor 2". Everything will be contained to this monitor when using only the graphics card and it will still show a second 480p monitor (this is the onboard graphics without drivers, still enabled as a failsafe) but you can't drag the mouse to it or use it now. When enabling the onboard's drivers again the two monitor setup disappears and it goes back to being shown as only one monitor so the two monitors actually disappear from settings.

Comment: Do you have an onboard gpu as well as an external one ?  It is not clear.  If you have any cables plugged into the other port, you should remove them.

Comment: Followed most of the instructions on your initial comment. Restarted, I used two monitors and the drivers. The new monitor was hooked up to nvidia unit and my old monitor had to be connected to the motherboard with the drivers on. It sorted itself out and changed my new monitor to 1 from now on. Read my update! Thanks.